# Why showing error 'the file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect'?

Tags: c#

While I am attempting to save the data to SQL database which includes image upload also, showing error:

> The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

But it doesn't show this error while running locally. Only after hosting  the application  in server .

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into candidates ( candidatephoto,    cookinglist) values ( @candiatephoto, @cookinglist)", connS);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@candiatephoto", uploadphoto.FileName.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cookinglist", uploadcook.FileName.ToString());
```

Comment: please put code,with it we can't help

Comment: I guess it may be something related to server path or configuration as it works fine locally, please edit your question putting your code will make it more clear

Comment: That's not a SQL Server error. Please post the code where the exception occurs. Most likely you are trying to access a file using an invalid file name. The code posted in the question is unrelated to the error

Comment: Post example for photo file name (uploadphoto.FileName value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally only happens when you use extended characters in a name anything outside a-z A-Z or 0-9.
likely source of problem is an ini file redirecting to the wrong folder/volume/file. solution find and edit it to the correct path. Also take all spaces out of the folder names.